# Drupal 7 - Views with Relationship and Filters issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-views-relationship

I'd like to create a View that shows all the users in a group (In this case a role) and their post count for a set date. I need it to also show the users who haven't posted. I can get this to work as long as there are no filters set. Once I add a date filter or one of the taxonomy term filters I have on the nodes, it stops showing the users who haven't posted within that date or used those terms.

The current view is a User type view and the relationship set to User: Content Authored and require this relationship is NOT checked.

Current View export:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'posts_by_group';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'Posts by Group';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Posts by Group';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access user profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '20';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'name' => 'name',
  'nid' => 'nid',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'name' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'desc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'nid' => array(
    'sortable' => 1,
    'default_sort_order' => 'desc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['empty_table'] = TRUE;
/* Relationship: User: Content authored */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['empty'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['empty_zero'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Field: COUNT(DISTINCT Content: Nid) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '# of Posts';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['empty'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: User: Roles */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['id'] = 'rid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['table'] = 'users_roles';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['field'] = 'rid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['value'] = array(
  15 => '15',
);
/* Filter criterion: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['id'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['field'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['operator'] = '>=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'date_filter_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['label'] = 'Start Date';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['operator'] = 'date_filter_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['identifier'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['required'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['remember'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  8 => 0,
  9 => 0,
  10 => 0,
  11 => 0,
  12 => 0,
  13 => 0,
  14 => 0,
  15 => 0,
  22 => 0,
  16 => 0,
  20 => 0,
  17 => 0,
  18 => 0,
  19 => 0,
  23 => 0,
  21 => 0,
  24 => 0,
  25 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['form_type'] = 'date_popup';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['default_date'] = 'now -30 days';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['date_fields'] = array(
  'node.created' => 'node.created',
);
/* Filter criterion: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['id'] = 'date_filter_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['field'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['operator'] = '<=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'date_filter_1_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['expose']['label'] = 'End Date';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['expose']['operator'] = 'date_filter_1_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['expose']['identifier'] = 'date_filter_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['expose']['required'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  8 => 0,
  9 => 0,
  10 => 0,
  11 => 0,
  12 => 0,
  13 => 0,
  14 => 0,
  15 => 0,
  22 => 0,
  16 => 0,
  20 => 0,
  17 => 0,
  18 => 0,
  19 => 0,
  23 => 0,
  21 => 0,
  24 => 0,
  25 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['form_type'] = 'date_popup';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['default_date'] = 'now';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter_1']['date_fields'] = array(
  'node.created' => 'node.created',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Sponsor (field_sponsor) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_sponsor_tid']['id'] = 'field_sponsor_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_sponsor_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_sponsor';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_sponsor_tid']['field'] = 'field_sponsor_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_sponsor_tid']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_sponsor_tid']['value'] = array(
  0 => '54',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_sponsor_tid']['reduce_duplicates'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_sponsor_tid']['vocabulary'] = 'sponsor';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'posts-by-group';
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields you are trying filter with will require the relationship.

Comment: Right, but is there a way to show these fields, even if the post count is 0? The date seems to be what kills it. I get a list of users in the group and a post count, then once the date is added, it drops all the people who haven't posted within that range. I'd like them to remain.

Comment: This is because of the views builds its queries. I would recommend turning on `Show SQL query`, so you have a better idea of what is happening.  Some good explanations, and how to alter a query [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11997/use-of-relationships-joins-in-views). They talk about `hook_views_pre_execute`, but there is also `hook_views_post_execute` and `hook_views_alter`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll have a look and report back.